# Python and Selenium: I am automating web scraping among pages. How can I loop by Next button?

Tags: python, selenium

I already written several lines of codes to pull url from this website.
http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/United%20States/hospitals

code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import csv

driver  = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.worldhospitaldirectory.com/United%20States/hospitals')
url     = []
pagenbr = 1

while pagenbr <= 115:
    current = driver.current_url
    driver.get(current)
    lks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
    for ii in lks:
        link = ii.get_attribute('href')
        if '/info' in link:
            url.append(link)

    print('page ' + str(pagenbr) + ' is done.')
    if pagenbr <=114:
        elm = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        elm.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    pagenbr += 1

ls = list(set(url))
with open('US_GeneralHospital.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for u in ls:
        wr.writerow([u])
```

And it worked very well to pull each individual links from this website.
But the problem is I need to change the page number I need to loop by myself every time.

I want to let this code upgrade to iterate by calculating how many time it need. Not by manually inputting.

Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. Your code is not going to get the stuff on page 115, as soon as it gets done with 114, it makes `pagenbr == 115` which terminates your while loop. 2. Use a for loop instead, `for pagenbr in range(1,116):` instead of your while loop. 3. Its not entirely clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad idea to hardcode the number of pages in your script. Try just to click "Next" button while it is enabled:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    try:
        # do whatever you need to do on page
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[not(@class="disabled")]/span[text()="Next"]').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

This should allow you to execute page scraping until the last page reached

Also note that using lines `current = driver.current_url` and `driver.get(current)` makes no sense at all, so you might skip them

Comment: Hi Anderson, you are my man. Thank you so much for helping me out